# how to make a css animation stop on the last nth-child css3

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a crossfade animation to stop on the last nth-child. I'm aware of animation-fill-mode: forwards , but it doesn't seem to work (I've tried putting it in different places to such as in the initial .crossfade declaration.)

Here's my html:

```
<body>
  <div class= "ad">
    <div class="crossfade">
      <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="image2.png" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="image3.png" alt="Image 3">
      <img src="image4.png" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
```

And my CSS is here:

```
.crossfade > img { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation-name: imageAnimation;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 43s linear 1 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 43s linear 1 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 43 linear 1 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 43 linear 1 0s;

}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 7s;
    -o-animation-delay: 7s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7s;
    animation-delay: 7s; 
}
.crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
    -o-animation-delay: 14s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
    animation-delay: 14s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 21s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 21s;
    -o-animation-delay: 21s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 21s;
    animation-delay: 21s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0%{ opacity:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1}
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0}
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0}
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0}
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this as an `example`, you could even try it like this, calling a declared `animation` again and again on `each child` after certain delay. 
Now `animation-fill-mode:forwards` takes into account the last `property` of animation that ends at `100%` i.e. on animation end what was the value of your `opacity` will be applied. In below example I have used `animation-fill-mode:forwards` for each `image` to perform that color-transition of images.

```css
div img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

div img:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: mv 10s linear forwards;
}

div img:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: mv 10s linear 10s forwards;
}

div img:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: mv 10s linear 20s forwards;
}

div img:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: mv 10s linear 30s forwards;
}

@keyframes mv {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/301/f22" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/302/f2f" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/303/ff2" alt="Image 3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304/2f2" alt="Image 4">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! You answered it really simply and that made sense. (I'm still a little bit new to css3). Am I right in understanding that declaring a new 'animation: ' each time sort of 'restarts' the animation for each individual child?

Side question: I'm currently following a tutorial and noticed you didn't need to use the -o-, -moz-, -webkit- in your answer. My understanding is that those are used to make it compatible with different browsers, but your version seems to work regardless. Is there a special case for when I would use those?  :] thanks heaps again.

Comment: @JessicaFoo This answer's solution doesn't _restart_ the animation, it create 4 animations, which is less performant than what I already posted in my answer (check my 2nd sample, which does the exactly same as this one does but more optimized), so I do not recommend to do it like this.

Comment: @JessicaFoo Also, the lack of prefixed properties doesn't work regardless, it works as you understood it, for older browsers, for which they are needed, and you should add them if you want your web site visitors having old browsers to also see the animation.

Comment: @frnt Can't understand why you post a solution based on 4 animations when the one I posted is a much efficient solution, and for sure one you yourself would use on your own web page. Is it more important for you to post an answer than to help users with a better way?

Comment: @Jessica Foo No you need to add other prefixes to make that work on other browsers, which I have not added as I already added refer this as an example and already a well explained solution by LGSon was added which tells about browser prefixes and other properties too. LGSon I have not used this codes in my websites, tag that I have used are totally different and that's why I added to refer as example, so OP could solve and understand how it worked. For me OP should understand how each property worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `@keyframes` rule ends with `opacity: 0` it doesn't matter if you use `forwards` or not, its end state will be `opacity: 0` for both.

One solution would be to add a 2nd `@keyframes` rule for the last item, together with `forwards`.

*Note, I removed all the prefixed properties to make is easier to parse the code. Also, the original code lacked a lot of the non prefixed, both properties and keyframe rules, and you should also always put the prefixed properties before the non prefixed*

```css
.crossfade > img { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: imageAnimation 43s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 1s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 7s; 
}
.crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 14s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 21s;
    animation-name: imageAnimationLast;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0%{ opacity:0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1}
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0}
}

@keyframes imageAnimationLast { 
    0%{ opacity:0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
    100% { opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class= "ad">
    <div class="crossfade">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/ff0" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/0ff" alt="Image 3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/00f" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Based on what you intend to do with those items and how they overlap, and as the 2nd is on top of the 3rd and so on, you could simply let the `@keyframes` rule stay at `opacity: 1`

```css
.crossfade > img { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: imageAnimation 43s ease-in 0s 1 forwards;
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 1s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 7s; 
}
.crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 14s; 
}

.crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 21s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0%{ opacity:0; }
    8% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class= "ad">
    <div class="crossfade">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/ff0" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/0ff" alt="Image 3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/00f" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
  </div>
```